# Simulation of LM384 / LM3886

Tags: simulation, multisim

I'd like to simulate an LM384/ LM3886 in Protues. but I can't find any library for them. can you help me?

Is there any library for pspice or another simulation software?

Comment: What do you mean by that slash? These are completely different parts. And what is "Protues"? Proteus maybe? You tagged your post with multisim, which is a different software. Although both are based on SPICE they don't necessarily run the same models because of the inevitable compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

TI provides the PSpice and TINA-TI models for the LM3886 on the [Tools and Software](http://www.ti.com/product/LM3886/toolssoftware) page. No such resources for the LM384; it's an old part and doesn't seem to have any available models.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really desperate for a spice model for an LM384 you could just build one up from the internal circuit shown in the data sheet: -

[image]

It won't be 100 % perfect and you'll need to do a bit of trial and error but you might in fact be doing the cheap end of the audio market a favour by creating a half decent model from the circuit.

Maybe look at it as a business/charity opportunity.